# any() doesn't return true?

Tags: python

I am working on a variation of the ceaser cipher. When I enter an encrypted message, my `decrypt()` function is supposed to keep decrypting with different rotation values until a common word, eg. "the" or "time" or "attack" pops up. For testing purposes, I'm using messages such as "Proceed to attack the base" so when the `any(word.upper() in plainText for word in subStrings)` part runs, it should return true, however it does not. My current code is as follows:

```
def decrypt(encryptedMessage):
    alphanumericAlphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]   # List of every letter in the alphabet

    message = (str(encryptedMessage).strip("\n")).upper()

    subStrings = ["The", "Base", "Proceed", "North", "West", "South", "East", "Hours", "Dawn", "Attack", "Defend", "Shoot", "Bearing", "Enemy", "Position", "Move", "That", "Fast", "Time", "Rise", "Loss", "Win", "Victory"]
    plainText = ""
    messageFound = False
    rotationValue = 0

    while messageFound != True:
        if any(word.upper() in plainText for word in subStrings): 
            messageFound = True
        else:
            plainText = ""
            for character in message:
                cipherIndex = alphanumericAlphabet.index(character.upper())
                plainIndex = cipherIndex - rotationValue
                if plainIndex < 0:
                    plainIndex += 36
                plainText += alphanumericAlphabet[plainIndex]
        rotationValue += 1

    print "Decrypted Message:", plainText, "\n", "Rotation:", rotationValue

    return plainText, rotationValue
```

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, because my message will be in uppercase, I will need my substrings to also be in uppercase and so I used `.upper()`

Comment: Also, wouldn't the message contain any other wild characters like # $ ~?

Comment: please don't change your title nor the content of your question

Comment: I rolled the 'Solved' edit back. Please mark any applicable answers as such by clicking the checkmark beside them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add space to the alphanumericdigit list for that character to also be processed or strip the whitespace:

```
def decrypt(encryptedMessage):
    alphanumericAlphabet = [" ","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]   # List of every letter in the alphabet

    message = (str(encryptedMessage).strip("\n")).upper()

    subStrings = ["The", "Base", "Proceed", "North", "West", "South", "East", "Hours", "Dawn", "Attack", "Defend", "Shoot", "Bearing", "Enemy", "Position", "Move", "That", "Fast", "Time", "Rise", "Loss", "Win", "Victory"]
    plainText = ""
    messageFound = False
    rotationValue = 0

    while messageFound != True:
        if any(word.upper() in plainText for word in subStrings):        
            messageFound = True
        else:
            plainText = ""
            for character in message:
                cipherIndex = alphanumericAlphabet.index(character)
                plainIndex = cipherIndex - rotationValue
                if plainIndex < 0:
                    plainIndex += 36
                plainText += alphanumericAlphabet[plainIndex]
        rotationValue += 1

    print("Decrypted Message:", plainText, "\n", "Rotation:", rotationValue)
    return plainText, rotationValue
decrypt("Proceed to attack the base")
Decrypted Message: PROCEED TO ATTACK THE BASE 
 Rotation: 2
Out[1852]:
('PROCEED TO ATTACK THE BASE', 2)
```

Comment: for your encrypted msg below, what should be the decryption. I get ('R3SJ1WTYFYNTSHNUMJWITJXSTYMF0JYTHMJHPKTWSZRGJWXGJHFZXJYMJ3MF0JGJJSFIIJIYTYMJFQUMFGJYFWWF3YMJSZRGJWX5YMWTZLMYTEMF0JGJJSFUUJSIJIYTYMJFQUMFGJYFWWF3YMNXRFPJXYMJFWWF38BHMFWFHYJWXQTSLNSXYJFITK7B1MJSNJSHW3UYR3HMFWFHYJWNTSQ3MF0JYTHMJHPYTXJJNKNYNXNSR3J2YJSIJIFQUMFGJYYMJSNKNSINYXNSIJ2YMJSNFIIR3WTYFYNTS0FQZJKNSFQQ3NYFPJYMJRTIZQTTWWJRFNSIJWFKYJWIN0NXNTSG38BYMNXYFPJXHFWJTKFS31WFUUNSLFWTZSIYMFYMFXYTGJITSJST1QJYZXXJJNK3TZMNLMQ3YWFNSJIUWTLWFRRJWXHFSHWFHPNYLTTIQZHP',
 14) You also need to expand subStrings list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line

```
cipherIndex = alphanumericAlphabet.index(character)
```

You have to check for the index of `character.upper()` as your alphanumericAlphabet only contains the upper case characters.

Comment: but character is already upper as `message = (str(encryptedMessage).strip("\n")).upper()`

Comment: You're right, sorry.

But the `alphanumericAlphabet` also doesn't contain `" "`, neither are spaces removed from the message. So when you try something like `decrypt("Proceed to attack the base")` it will actually fail, won't it?

Comment: add whitespace to the alphanumericAlphabet or strip the mesage of it

Comment: So when I run `decrypt("Proceedtoattackthebase")` it returns
`Decrypted Message: PROCEEDTOATTACKTHEBASE
Rotation: 2`
Is this not what you expect?